# Sharepoint 2013. After successfully completed Register-SPWorkflowService command Workflow still is Not Connected at central administration

Tags: workflow, 2013

Sharepoint 2013. 
After successfully completed Register-SPWorkflowService command Workflow still is Not Connected at central administration.

After retry to register WF I`ve got following error:

PS C:\Users\Administrator> Register-SPWorkflowService -SPSite http:// my_site_name
 -WorkflowHostUri http:// windows_wf_azure_host_name :12291 -AllowOAuthHttp

Register-SPWorkflowService : The trusted provider certificate which is already
in use.
At line:1 char:1
+ Register-SPWorkflowService -SPSite http:// my_site_name  -WorkflowHostUri
http://...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...WorkflowService:
   RegisterSPWorkflowService) [Register-SPWorkflowService], InvalidOperationE
  xception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.PowerShell
   .RegisterSPWorkflowService

Answer (score 2):

Try with -Force. This will overwrite old params. Can be useful also in other cases when there is "something" registered but e.g. with errors.

Comment: I've rerun the cmdlet with -force, but CA still says Workflow is not connected, any other additional tips?